# GC Log roation with compression paramewter in JDK 8

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I am trying GC log rotation in JDK 8.So I have achieved it by using below GC Log JVM parameter

```
-XX:+PrintGCDetails  -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps  -Xloggc:verbose-jdk8-gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps 
-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=1k
```

But Now I want that This should also compressed when Rotation is done.
So is there any JVM Parameter in JDK 8 for compression of GC Log ?
Is there any one who can help me.

Comment: What do you exactly mean with compession? Zipping?

Comment: why does the JDK have to do that for you? you could just set a cron job or a file watch service that compresses rotated files for you. or use a filesystem that supports compression. more of a general sysadmin problem than JVM.

Comment: You have 5 logs of 1 KB, but this is too much?  I would allow it to use a few MB and not worry about it.

Comment: Yes I know that i can set crontab for compression.But I want to know that is there any parameter in JVM that do the job of compression. And here it is just example that file size is  1k . Actually in production i will do with other size.

Comment: HI Guys, I have another question that is there any parameter in JVM(JDK 8) That I can rotate GC log based on specific time.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, you can use logroate: https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate to manage the rotation and compression of JVM gc log.